Why should I use CameraDevice in JavaCV?
I am developing a desktop app that works as a webcam for a project for an universitary exam. This cam should perform several tasks into the app.

I can't understand the purpose of JavaCV's class CameraDevice. How could I exploit it?

Comparing FrameGrabber and CameraDevice classes I can't see any advantage using the second one, that, according to its name, should be a proper implementation of some device that works as camera (for example a webcam).
I'll explain: to create FrameGrabbers (see method createFrameGrabber()) with custom settings just as in CameraDevice I need to give a CameraDevice.Settings (previously setted one by one) to the constructor (these settings will be assigned to the FrameGrabber when you call createFrameGrabber()), the same way I can use FrameGrabber and set its settings one by one using its own methods, exactly at the same way I did before, but avoiding the CameraDevice's usage (and taking the advantage to give custom settings to every FrameGrabber which I create).


Please, if someone uses or has used that class, can give me a reason to use it?

CameraDevice is an API from OpenCV, while FrameGrabber is something loosely equivalent in JavaCV. You can choose to use the one appropriate for your application.
